# Angular: formArray values aren't modified when I push new data in it

Tags: angular, forms, formarray

I have a reactive form includes array of 'fields' and after adding new fields to the array and printing the form or submitting it, the new fields are not added to it.
I read about patchValue method, but it's still not working.

Actually, I have second level inside 'fields' array to deal with, but I need to solve the first level problem first.

Here is the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzi9ga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below you're getting `Array` of controls instead of `FormArray`.

```
this.selectedForm.get('fields')['controls']
```

To get `FormArray` you should be using

```
this.selectedForm.get('fields')
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eepxb3?file=app/app.component.html)**